# how to programmatically display the bottom row in virtual ListView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I have a virtual ListView in Winforms which nicely displays the contents from a database.  Items get asynchronously added to the database and are visible when I pull the scrollbar to the bottom.

Now I would like to insure that whenever the asynchronous thread adds to the database it also updates the ListView so that it knows which index should be the bottom row.  Before I added the ListView object, I could do that with a ListBox where I set which index should be the top index, based on itemheight and listbox height:

```
int numItems = listBox1.ClientSize.Height / listBox1.ItemHeight;
if (listBox1.TopIndex == listBox1.Items.Count - numItems - 1)
    listBox1.TopIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - numItems + 1;
```

Unfortunately neither ItemHeight nor TopIndex exist in ListView.

But the major question is: How do I tell the virtual ListView that it should display a specific range of indexes - or insure that some index gets displayed?

Comment: why not use event CollectionChanged? listview need to be notified of data source changes if you want display new row.

Comment: @Na Na: Not sure how to use CollectionChanged, which is part of ObservableCollection<T>.  Can you show an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the property `TopItem` to set the top visible item in the `ListView` (no matter it's in virtual mode or not):

```
listView1.TopItem = listView1.Items[itemIndex];//itemIndex is the index of the item 
//you want to make visible as the top item.
```

Comment: I thought we couldn't play with Items when in virtual mode.  But this works just fine.  Thanks!